# Getting NAN when only dealing with integer and float

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am working on an opengl assignment where I have to make a creature (I chose a snowman) move around some terrain.  I am trying to make it move around, and I am getting the strangest errors.  After printing the numbers out, I frequently get "-1.#QNAN0" as a number.  I don't even know what that means.  Below is the snowman's update function, constructor, and the header file.  I am trying to get 2 numbers to use as velocity and add them to the position while it is set to animate (randomly changing), but I don't understand what errors are causing me to not get numbers out of rand().

Each time that the probability check succeeds, it prints out:

```
DEBUG: probability check succeeded
-1.#QNAN0 0.000000
```

or

```
DEBUG: probability check succeeded
0.000000 0.000000
```

with about 50% chance of each.

From Snowman.cpp

```
void Snowman::update(canvas_t texture){
//randomly toggle the walking variable
int probability = rand() % 100;
//printf("DEBUG: probability = %d\n", probability);
if(probability <= 10){
    printf("DEBUG: probability check succeeded\n");
    walking = !walking;
    dx = static_cast<float>(( (rand() % 10) - 5));
    dy = static_cast<float>(( (rand() % 10) - 5));
    printf("%f %f\n", dx, dy);
}
//code to control movement
if(walking){
    animate = true;
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    constrain(x, 0, texture.width);
    constrain(y, 0, texture.height);
}else{
    animate = false;
}

//set the height after x and y are resolved
z = getHeight(texture);
}


Snowman::Snowman(canvas_t terrain)
{
wireFrame = false;
animate = false;
armSegments = 2;
animationFrameNumber = 0;
manualUserOffset = 0;

//set its initial position
x = rand() % terrain.width;
y = rand() % terrain.height;
dx = 0;
dy = 0;
}
```

From Snowman.h

```
class Snowman
{
public:
Snowman(canvas_t);
~Snowman(void);

void setWireframe(bool);
void toggleWireframe(void);
void setAnimate(bool);
void toggleAnimate(void);
void setArmSegments(int);
void addArmSegment(void);
void subtractArmSegment(void);

void update(canvas_t);
void draw(void);

private:
bool wireFrame;
bool animate;
bool walking;
int armSegments;
int animationFrameNumber;
float manualUserOffset;

float x, y, z;
int dx, dy;

inline float f(void);
inline void drawMouth(int headRadius);
inline void drawFace(int headRadius);
void drawArm(int remainingSegments);
inline void drawBody();
inline float getHeight(canvas_t);
};
```

Comment: The `static_cast<float>` is Perfectly Pointless. No matter how much you stamp your feet and insist that you have a float value, you're still just assigning it to an integer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dx` and `dy` are `int`s, but your format specifier `%f` requires a `double` or a `float`. So you have *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: I thought I had a float there.  I don't know how I missed that after combing through it for hours.  I'm going to go bang my head on a wall now

Comment: @user2309865: Self-harm is never the Acceptable Answer :-S